# HOW socket test by cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, io, cypress

i used cypress for test socket programming.
but socket not connect in cypress.

```
import { WebSocket, Server } from 'mock-socket'

describe('restfull test', () => {

    let mockSocket;
    let mockServer;
    var ob = {
        app: 415,
        match: 1488,
        statePercent: {
            11: 0,
            13: 0,
        },
        type: "start"
    }


    it('Does not do much!', () => {
        let url = "wss://test"
        mockServer = new Server(url)
        mockServer.on('connection', socket => {
            console.log('connect')
            mockSocket = socket
            console.log(socket)

        });
        mockSocket = new WebSocket(url)
        mockSocket.send(JSON.stringify(ob))
        console.log(cy)

    })
```

not connect and send by websocket .
please help me